# How to stop audio from playing when back button is pressed?

Tags: android

Hi all here is my code:

```
   final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image7);
   imageView.setImageResource(mFullSizeIds[position]);
   imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Audio.this,mAudio[position]);  
    mp.start();

}

  });
```

Now this code works fine to play the audio when the user taps the image, however when I want to exit this activity and go to a different activity, the audio track is still playing, even when I press the home key the audio is still playing.  How can I prevent this from happening?
Is there a way to stop the track from playing when the user taps the image again or presses the back/home button?

Comment: In your `onPause` use `mp.stop()` and `mp.release()`.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed ()
    {
      if (mp != null)
        mp.stop();
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

and

```
@Override
public void onPause ()
{
  if (mp != null)
  {
    mp.pause();
    mp.stop();
  }
  super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an onStop in the activity and make mp a class variable although I always create/prefer media player helper class for this sort of stuff. Then call mp.stop()/pause on onStop.

```
private MediaPlayer mp = null;

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
    }
}
```

then you just create it with removing the MediaPlayer before mp:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(Audio.this,mAudio[position]);
```

Comment: Could you please explain how to create an 'onStop' in my activity and how to make mp a class variable?

Comment: updated answer, basically you create MediaPlayer mp from outside the methods this will mean its accessible from any methods inside your activity.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that it works!! however when I select the next image the previous image's audio track doesn't stop as it previously did it just plays over the previous image. Any idea what could cause that now?

Comment: check if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop(); if you are reusing the same object.

Comment: No luck. all the audio track in my 'Integer' are listed and when the user selects the next image in the gallery it plays the track for that image. Isn't there a way of stopping the track when the user selects the next image in the gallery?  I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: try to release it as well, mp.stop(); mp.release(); before playing the other one.

Comment: No that doesn't seem to work the audio doesn't play at all now.

Comment: I just looked into one of my games and what I did was create mp for each audio file. It's possible that the stop/play is not synchronous. So you could either create 2 media players or media player for each. if 2 mediaplayer you would set other mediaplayer like prevMP, nextMP, and mp or create a SparseArray<MediaPlayer> with index resourceId.

Comment: Thanks I will try that in the morning as my brain has just about switched off now.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onBackPressed` method, and stop your `MediaPlayer` object, which is `mp`.